# For tour and travel packages, should I use the Product or Service schema markups?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

If a company lists tour and travel packages on their site with proper price info and a link to book that package online, could such pages use the [Product](https://schema.org/Product) category from `schema.org`?

As far as I know, the *Product* schema should only be used if the product is a tangible item.

If not, should I use the [Service](https://schema.org/Service) category with nested *Offer* markups for such pages instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it has a price and/or if it can be booked, you have to use an [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) item.

The item that gets offered could be a `Product` (this is not only for tangible things!), a `Service`, an `Event`, or a `CreativeWork`.

I think in your case [`Event`](http://schema.org/Event) might make sense, but this ultimately depends on your specific case (your understanding of the tour/travel packages) and which properties you want to provide. `Event` is only appropriate if the date of the tour/travel is settled. If it’s instead something like a boilerplate, `Product` or `Service` should be used.

Note that you don’t *have* to provide an item for the thing which you offer. If you don’t need more properties (and if you don’t want to provide the additional data that something is an `Event` or whatever), you could use `Offer` only.

Properties:

- `Event`/`Product`/… → [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers) → `Offer`¹
- `Organization` → [`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer) → `Offer`²

¹ inverse in case of `Product`/`Service`: [`itemOffered`](http://schema.org/itemOffered)

² inverse: [`offeredBy`](http://schema.org/offeredBy)

Comment: Thanks Unor, I was expecting your answer only. You cleared my confusion. One more small question, the website is selling tour packages but there are no specific dates for city tour or country tour. So I think Product or Service one of them can be used, as you mentioned. Now Service schema won't make the website eligible to get Rich Snippets on organic search right?

Comment: @Sanchit: Yes, according to [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products) and their testing tool, the Products Rich Snippet does not work with `Service`. Maybe this is intentional, or maybe this is because they didn’t update it yet (using `Service` with `offers` etc. is only possible since the current version of Schema.org: 2.2). The [Product](http://schema.org/Product) type still says (and probably will keep it) that it’s for "Any offered product **or service**."